# MPMoviePlayerController UIGestureRecognizer doesn't fire when in full screen

Tags: ios, ios6, mpmovieplayercontroller, uigesturerecognizer

I have MPMoviePlayerController which has some UIGestureRecognizers. It works well in normal view but when the player entered to fullscreen it doesn't fire the events even the events are binded.

Here is how I bind my events:

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer * nextChannelRecognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(gotoNextChannel)];
    [nextChannelRecognizer setDirection:(UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft)];
    [[player.view.subviews objectAtIndex:0] setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    [[player.view.subviews objectAtIndex:0] addGestureRecognizer:nextChannelRecognizer];

    UISwipeGestureRecognizer * previousChannelRecognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(gotoPreviousChannel)];
    [previousChannelRecognizer setDirection:(UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight)];
    [[player.view.subviews objectAtIndex:0] addGestureRecognizer:previousChannelRecognizer];

    for (UIGestureRecognizer *g in ((UIView *)[player.view.subviews objectAtIndex:0]).gestureRecognizers) {
        NSLog(@"g %@", g.class);
    }
```

In normal view and fullscreen the code in the loop outputs these

MPTapGestureRecognizer
MPSwipeGestureRecognizer
UIPinchGestureRecognizer
MPActivityGestureRecognizer
UITapGestureRecognizer
UITapGestureRecognizer
UIPinchGestureRecognizer
UISwipeGestureRecognizer
UISwipeGestureRecognizer

I tried add another temp view with view bounds of the player's view and bind the same events to it but result was same.

Can you tell me why it doesn't work? What is wrong?